# How can you get notified, if a volume is still used by an application?

Tags: cocoa, callback, volume, diskarbitration, unmount

If you have a document open and want to unmount a volume, os x opens this alert panel, that the document is still in use by program x.
How can you get notified about this in cocoa?
I tried the DADiskArbitration framework, but this doesn't send a callback until the disk has successfully unmounted.

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke [`lsof`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) using [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get a list of open files. Use `lsof +D /Volumes/<volume name>` to narrow the search down to files open in the mounted volume you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it out. I should mention that I have no experience with NSTask. Is there no library or framework to do that?

Comment: `NSTask` is really easy to use, there's no need for an additional library or framework. It's part of Foundation.framework. There's an example here: http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=nstask

Comment: OK, I get the task working and get string as output. This is not the only problem, but if I have for example a pdf open in preview, the task returns me three open files, all the same but in different "COMMANDS" (applications), namely finder preview and QuickLook.

Comment: Parse the output and put all the file paths in an `NSSet` so that duplicate paths are filtered out, and now you have a collection of unique file paths.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out with your help. Though the parsing is a bit complicated to turn a string into objects. If someone needs the sourcecode, please email me.